# Computed is not defined

Tags: vue.js, debugging, vuejs2, nuxt.js, vue-composition-api

I've got a error where computed is not defined, I can't seem to find how to solve this, even after placing it in `computed: {}`

```html
<template>
  <component :is="tag" v-html="sanitizedContent" />
</template>
<script>
import { defineComponent } from "@nuxtjs/composition-api";

import DOMPurify from "isomorphic-dompurify";

export default defineComponent({
  name: "HTMLContent",
  sanitizedContent: computed(() => DOMPurify.sanitize(props.content)),
  props: {
    tag: {
      type: String,
      default: "div",
    },
    content: {
      type: String,
      default: "",
    },
  },
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By looking at your code, you could make it better like this:

Import the missing `computed` from `"@nuxtjs/composition-api"`, and add the missing `setup` function, returning the value you want.

```html
<template>
  <component :is="tag" v-html="sanitizedContent" />
</template>
<script>
import { computed, defineComponent } from "@nuxtjs/composition-api";
import DOMPurify from "isomorphic-dompurify";

export default defineComponent({
  name: "HTMLContent",
  props: {
    tag: {
      type: String,
      default: "div",
    },
    content: {
      type: String,
      default: "",
    },
  },
  setup(props) {
    return {
      sanitizedContent: computed(() => DOMPurify.sanitize(props.content)),
    }
  }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 5):

Did you try to import it:

```
import { computed } from "vue";
```

and:

```
const sanitizedContent = computed(() => DOMPurify.sanitize(props.content))
```

Comment: Does not seem to be the solution since it returns: TypeError
Object(...) is not a function ...

Comment: @Craws hey mate, I updated my answer, take a look again pls

Comment: Thanks mate! Where would one place the const? If I reference it in the <component> and place the const under setup() { .. It has a no refference in the IDE and a Object(...) is not a function error on runtime